# Showing the data received from db in radio_button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Versions: Rails 4.2.5 & Ruby 2.2.
I am using radio_button_tag in my form_tag.

```
- options = ['Yes', 'No']
- options.each do |option|
  = radio_button_tag 'val[0]', '#{option}', false
  = label_tag( "#{option}")
```

While saving, the data is saved properly(We are saving data as Hash) & also retrieved properly. But the data is not reflected in the radio_button_tag.

For this I have added the radio_button_tag as:

```
= radio_button_tag 'val[0]', '#{option}', @value[:val][0]
```

Its always selects the 'No' radio button. The html generated has both checked='checked'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed this code to look something like this:

```
  = radio_button_tag 'val[0]', 1, @value[:val][0] == '1'
  %label{for: 'val_0_1'} Yes
  = radio_button_tag 'val[0]', 0, @value[:val][0] == '0'
  %label{for: 'val_0_0'} No
```

We were getting strings from the database, so it was unable to process further & in HTML, both comes as checked, so it selects always the last one.